# Cannot find the most recent google blogs using blogger API

Tags: ios, blogger

I am working on a blog reader iOS app that retrieves posts from all the google blogs given a URL and API key.

But all I get are blogs from 2016.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/10861780/posts?key=YOUR-API-KEY
```

I have made sure my api key has been placed correctly and that the blogger API has been enabled.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please read the documentation: https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using, under "Retrieving a blog by its URL".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The provided API retrieves posts, not blogs, so I guess it's posts that you're looking for.

The blogid you're using is for Google's own Blogger page. Latest post is indeed from Nov 2016: https://googleblog.blogspot.com/index.html

Comment: Posts from a specific blog, in this case google yes.
Is there a way to search for other blogs to obtain their blogID?

Comment: This seems to be a new question. Hiding it in the comments to my answer will make it hard for people to help you with that. I suggest opening a new question and marking this as the answer

Comment: It's ok. I found a blogger search engine that can search for bloggers.